# How do I tell intellij to resume macro execution on failed command?

Tags: intellij-idea, macros

I tried to setup an intellij macro that

1. optimizes the imports of the current file (Code -> Optimize Imports)
2. reformats the current file (Code -> Reformat Code)

[image]

But whenever there are no imports to optimize (balloon tip: "Unused imports not found"), the second action won't run. The same is true if I would reorder the two tasks: whenever the code is formatted already, the imports won't get optimized.

I'm suspecting the problem to be the "exit codes" of the single commands to cancel the macro-execution. Is there a way to tell intellij that I want to have both of my commands executed either way?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. Are there any errors shown in UI or in idea.log (Help | Show Log in ... action) file?

Comment: Report a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA if problem remains with steps to reproduce and idea.log attached after reproducing.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply: After your comment I tested again and it worked without me changing any configurations .
The bummer: After working a bit with my code (formatting only, no import changes), it stopped working again. I took a look into the idea.log file and found no errors. The only entries were those:

Comment: 2020-12-28 21:53:41,778 [47768538]   INFO - rojectCodeStyleSettingsManager - Saving Project code style 
    2020-12-28 21:53:41,780 [47768540]   INFO - rojectCodeStyleSettingsManager - Project code style saved 
    2020-12-28 21:54:03,554 [47790314]   INFO - rojectCodeStyleSettingsManager - Saving Project code style 
    2020-12-28 21:54:03,555 [47790315]   INFO - rojectCodeStyleSettingsManager - Project code style saved

Comment: These four lines resulted from triggering the above shortcut two times (I wanted to be sure I only triggered the shortcut). The footer of idea showed it collecting and optimizing the imports, but no lines have been formatted - although there were lines to (re)format.